# Synchronize Digg Reader and Feedly

Tags: automation, rss, rss-reader, digg, feedly

I need to connect Feedly and another online RSS/podcast reader, Digg Reader.
I want to synchronize them.
If I subscribe something in Feedly, I want the subscription to be automatically added in Digg Reader.

I did the same using IFTTT with Diigo and Delicious, but I don't know how to do it with Feedly and Digg Reader, using IFTTT or any other services.

EDIT: how stated below, I can import/export opml files in those online service, but I want to make it automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at would be "OPML subscriptions"... but AFAIK, this does not exist in neither Feedly nor Digg.

Now, another "trick" would work and provide the same "result", even though this is not exactly what you're looking for.

If you use a service to "combine" these feeds and generate another feed, you could subscribe to this new feed in both Digg and Feedly. You would then have the exact same content in both reader with a single subscription.
To combine these feeds, you could use [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com/) (as an API) or services like [Chimpfeedr](http://chimpfeedr.com/).

Comment: Can you explain me a little more how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, the two readers would have to let you subscribe to a subscription list, not just to feeds.

As far as I know, neither Feedly or Digg support this feature.

All of my RSS readers going back to Radio UserLand have had this feature, including my latest, River4.

Comment: I can suscribe to a subscription list using opml import/export, in Feedly and Digg Reader. I tried, it works. But I like to automate the process.

Comment: That's more like "import" than "subscribe."

Comment: Yes, but it makes no difference, it add RSS, and I'de like to automate it.